# How to create a stateless and static Halogen component?

Tags: purescript, halogen

Consider this snippet from github, https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/master/examples/basic/src/Button.purs#L42 which tries to render an html button using halogen library.

```
render :: State -> H.ComponentHTML Query
  render state =
    let
      label = if state then "On" else "Off"
    in
      HH.button
        [ HP.title label
        , HE.onClick (HE.input_ Toggle)
        ]
        [ HH.text label ]

  eval :: Query ~> H.ComponentDSL State Query Message m
  eval = case _ of
    Toggle next -> do
      state <- H.get
      let nextState = not state
      H.put nextState
      H.raise $ Toggled nextState
      pure next
    IsOn reply -> do
      state <- H.get
      pure (reply state)
```

Is there any possible way to get the most 'barebone' UI control, just to render a static UI component, without states involved?

Comment: If you want a static UI component without any state, maybe you don't need a Halogen component at all. Can you not just render static HTML in its place in the parent component?

Answer (score 1):

How about setting `type State = Unit`? Then your `render` function would look like

```
render :: State -> H.ComponentHTML Query
render _ = [...]
```

i.e. just ignore the parameter (since you can't get any information out of a `Unit` value anyway).